# is there a way to select the default keyboard language in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, keyboard

I want to show a keyboard in English and disable the ability to change the language, is there a way to do so ?

I'm basically trying to show a keyboard for the user to enter an OTP in English only.

I have added this to `inputFormatters` in the `TextField` :

```
                WhitelistingTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly,
```

and that does not accept ١٢٣... it accepts 123.. which is intended behaviour but the issue is when a user has arabic keyboard.